# How big should big_num be for big_num % small_num to give a good distribution?

Tags: hash, distribution, modulus

I've got a fixed-sized table, lets say it has N indexes.

I've got a large number generated at random, in the range [0-M].

How big should M be so that M % N will give a good distribution to indexes in my table?

Sorry if this is a basic question, my understanding of stats has slipped since I left the final exam XD

Comment: By "good distribution," you mean uniform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't matter much, although being a multiple of N (or close to one) will help around the edges, especially for smaller M. The more important thing is that your random numbers are evenly distributed between 0 and M.

Comment: great, thanks.  my random numbers are coming directly from SHA256 hashes, and so I suppose that if we call sha256 an ideal hash function, the results are as good as truly random?